# Get list of on-behalf of users permission - EWS Manage API

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to get list of email address which user can send email on behalf of.

This is an application which sends email on behalf of users, so app does not have user credential. Instead, app is registered in Azure AD and has full permission to `Office 365 Exchange Online`. App generates a JWT token and this used for exchange credentials which works fine and currently application able to send emails on behalf of users.

```
User     Email
A        a@test.com
B        b@test.com
C        c@test.com
D        d@test.com
```

If user A can send the email on behalf of users B,C and D, I am trying to get email addresses of user B,C,D. So currently user A has given permission to send as B,C or D.

I was trying below code

```
  var Service = new ExchangeService.ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);               
  Service.TraceFlags = ExchangeService.TraceFlags.None;
  Service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "a@test.com");
  Service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");
  Service.EnableScpLookup = false;
  Service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
  Service.Credentials = new ExchangeService.OAuthCredentials(token);
  var result= Service.GetDelegates("a@test.com", true);
```

This is now giving me error

> ```
> ExchangeImpersonation SOAP header must be present for this type of OAuth token
>
> ErrorCode = ErrorInvalidExchangeImpersonationHeaderData
> ```

In [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/responsecode) it says this is when *" a caller does not specify a UPN, an e-mail address, or a user SID. This will also occur if the caller specifies one or more of those and the values are empty"*

But this token is app only token where app has given full permission to `Office 365 Exchange Online` in azure portal.

Not sure if I am heading to right direction to solve this? Alternate way or anyway to fix this

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the line

```
 Service.AutodiscoverUrl("a@test.com", (discoverURL) => true);
```

Because you have already hard-coded the EWS Endpoint URL in

```
 Service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

and with Office365 there is only one endpoint which is what you have set so even if AutodiscoverUrl returned a result it would be the same URL.